# Fortran interface to call a C function that returns a pointer to an array

Tags: arrays, pointers, interface, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

After much searching, I found what I believe to be the closest answer to my problem is on Stack Overflow (SO) at [Fortran interface to call a C function that return a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852790/fortran-interface-to-call-a-c-function-that-return-a-pointer), (posted nearly 10 years ago!)

I quote this because using that example keeps the code simple and still illustrates my problem.

I want to return an array that has been created/memory allocated in C++ and be able to analyse the answer in Fortran, because that is where the bulk of the code for this application lies. My application goes off into C++ to produce the integer array answer and returns it to the Fortran program via the C interface. The original SO example used a single double precision variable as the return. I’ve changed it to integer because that is what I will be dealing with in my application. The example code (as changed) works.

I have highlighted with comments the changes that I have tried to make to return an array pointer, but I’ve run out of ideas. (I could say, “Oh for the bad old days when I could just equivalence an integer to an iarray(1) and go beyond the size of the array”, but I won’t. It’s good to have coding protections, but sometimes it gets frustrating.)

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Intel Fortran parallel_studio_xe_2019_update5_composer.

My modified example of the original SO code:

```
! ps_test_pointers.f90

program foo
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_ptr,        &
                                          c_f_pointer,  &
                                          c_int
  implicit none
  type(c_ptr) :: c_p!(:) ! <-------
  integer(c_int), pointer :: f_p!(:) ! <-------

  interface
    function foofunc() bind(c)
      import :: c_ptr
      implicit none  
      type(c_ptr) :: foofunc!(:) ! <-------
    end function foofunc
  end interface

  c_p = foofunc()
  call c_f_pointer(c_p, f_p)
  print *, f_p

end program foo
```

```c
// ps_test_pointersC.cpp : 'Subroutine' only.

extern "C" {

    int bar[3] = { 2, 3, 4 };
    
    int *foofunc() {
        return bar;
    }

}
```

As I said above, the code works, in the sense that it prints out the first element of the array (‘2’).

If I add the ‘(:)’ to the definition of f_p, the code compiles without error, but when I run it, the program fails with the run-time error: “forrtl: severe (408): fort: (7): Attempt to use pointer F_P when it is not associated with a target” at the line “call c_f_pointer(c_p, f_p)”.

I have tried declaring c_p as an array (“c_p(:)”), but I get the same error in the same place.

I have also tried calling c_p as an argument to a subroutine – still only using integers:

```
    ! ps_test_pointers.f90
    
    program foo
      use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_ptr,        &
                                              c_f_pointer,  &
                                              c_int
      implicit none
      type(c_ptr) :: c_p!(:) ! <-------
      integer(c_int), pointer :: f_p!(:) ! <-------
    
      interface
        subroutine foofunc(c_p) bind(c)
          import :: c_ptr
          implicit none  
          type(c_ptr) :: c_p!(:) ! <-------
        end subroutine foofunc
      end interface
    
      call foofunc(c_p)
      call c_f_pointer(c_p, f_p)
      print *, f_p
    
    end program foo
```

```c
    // ps_test_pointersC.cpp : 'Subroutine' only.
    
    extern "C" {
    
        int bar[3] = { 2, 3, 4 };
        
        void foofunc(int *rtn) {
            rtn = bar;
        }
    
    }
```

but the created pointer in the C function never gets assigned to c_p on return (hence f_p is never defined).

Reading around the problem, I hope I’m not at the bleeding edge of compiler implementation and have exposed a problem between restrictions tightening but not coping with all the use cases!

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RE the subroutine approach, I think we probably need to declare `c_p` as `int**` (rather than `int*`) on the C/C++ side to get the address of `bar` via argument association (rather than function return value). So something like...

main.f90:

```
program foo
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_ptr,        &
                                          c_f_pointer,  &
                                          c_int
  implicit none
  type(c_ptr) :: c_p
  integer(c_int), pointer :: f_p(:)
  integer(c_int) :: nsize

  interface
    subroutine foosub( c_p, nsize ) bind(c)
      import :: c_ptr, c_int
      implicit none  
      type(c_ptr)    :: c_p    !<-- sends the pointer to c_p
      integer(c_int) :: nsize  !<-- sends the pointer to nsize
    end subroutine
  end interface

  call foosub( c_p, nsize )
  call c_f_pointer( c_p, f_p, [nsize] )

  print *, "nsize  = ", nsize
  print *, "f_p(:) = ", f_p(:)

end program
```

sub.cpp:

```
extern "C" {
    int bar[3] = { 2, 3, 4 };
    
    void foosub( int** rtn, int* nsize ) {
        *rtn = bar;
        *nsize = sizeof(bar) / sizeof(int);
    }
 }
```

Compile & run:

```
$ g++-10 -c sub.cpp
$ gfortran-10 -c main.f90
$ g++-10 main.o sub.o -lgfortran
$ ./a.out
 nsize  =            3
 f_p(:) =            2           3           4
```

Comment: @francescalus Ah, okay :) Thanks much! (I would also like to try that descriptor, but no experience yet...)

Comment: Thanks @roygvib. Your worked example was most useful - and I could repeat it in my environment :)  My real environment from C++, where I just have a pointer returned, represents the start of an array. When I get it back into Fortran, I have the "f_p" array defined, but not the individual elements (yet). I just need to learn a little more about how to make my C pointer look like an array! I'm confident I can get there now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Your C function is returning a pointer scalar; you want to associate this target with a Fortran array.  This means you have the declarations

```
type(c_ptr) :: c_p                  ! <- scalar address
integer(c_int), pointer :: f_p(:)   ! <- array to associate
```

In the call to `c_f_pointer` you specify the shape of the Fortran pointer array with another argument.  However, in this case the Fortran side has no way of knowing how large the array returned by the C function is.

Consider:

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
implicit none

type(c_ptr) :: c_p
integer(c_int), pointer :: f_p(:)

interface
    function foofunc() bind(c)
      import :: c_ptr
      implicit none  
      type(c_ptr) :: foofunc
    end function foofunc
end interface

c_p = foofunc()
call c_f_pointer(c_p, f_p, [3])
print *, f_p

end
```

If you don't like the magic number `3` you'll need to find some other way to get that number (as you would if this function were being called in a C world).  You can have the length as an extra argument, as with [roygvib's subroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63414203/3157076) example, as a linkage associated extra variable, through a separate query call (such as how for a character array one may use `strnlen`), etc.

Alternatively, if you want to be very fancy and you have flexibility in the language interface, you can use "improved interoperability" features in a C subroutine to do Fortran memory management:

```
program foo
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_int

  implicit none
  integer(c_int), pointer :: f_p(:)

  interface
     subroutine foosub(f_p) bind(c)
       import c_int
       implicit none  
       integer(c_int), pointer, intent(out) :: f_p(:)
     end subroutine foosub
  end interface
    
  call foosub(f_p)
  print *, f_p
    
end program foo
```

```c
#include "ISO_Fortran_binding.h"

int bar[3] = { 2, 3, 4 };
        
void foosub(CFI_cdesc_t* f_p) {
  CFI_index_t nbar[1] = {3};
  CFI_CDESC_T(1) c_p;

  CFI_establish((CFI_cdesc_t* )&c_p, bar, CFI_attribute_pointer, CFI_type_int,
                nbar[0]*sizeof(int), 1, nbar);
  CFI_setpointer(f_p, (CFI_cdesc_t *)&c_p, NULL);
}
```

You could also use an allocatable variable instead of a pointer variable if you prefer.

This approach is not available with a Fortran function because interoperable functions cannot have array, pointer or allocatable results.