# Calliing the SuperLU library in my Fortran program

Tags: compilation, fortran

I'm trying to get this superLU sparse matrix solver to run, but I can't seem to compile it. I'm writing my program with Fortran, and so I'm trying to call superLU from my program. I'm using g95 compiler for fortran.

http://crd.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/#superlu

How can I compile this in Fortran? I tried and it said error `cannot exec 'cc1'`, no file found. I don't care what Fortran compiler I use, just any way I can call this superLU from Fortran.

I don't know much about linking Fortran with C++ programs, what I did is `g95 -o test f77_main.f hbcode1.f c_fortran_dgssv.c`

Comment: Your second link didn't get through, probably because your rep is too low. Post it in a comment

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the use of the Fortran ISO C Binding for calling C routines from Fortran, or vice-a-versa.  This binding, which is part of Fortran 2003 but widely available for several years, informs Fortran to use C calling conventions.   It is part of the language and so compiler and platform independent.   Besides previous answers here, there are code examples in the gfortran manual under "Mixed-Language Programming".  There are also many examples of Fortran interfaces to call the C routines of the GNU Scientific Library at http://www.lrz.de/services/software/mathematik/gsl/fortran/index.html.

Re how to compile & link a mixed Fortran & C program ... generally is easier to use the Fortran compiler for the linking step because it brings in extra Fortran runtime libraries.    So proceed in two steps: compile your C routines to object files, then in the next step compile the Fortran routines and link the Fortran routines and the pre-compiled C routines.    If using C++, use "extern C" to make it compatible with C.    So, for example:

gcc -c MyCRoutine.c

gfortran FortranMain.f95  MyCRoutine.o

Answer (score 0):

A good start to solving your problem can be found in a previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902186/pass-fortran-77-function-to-c-c/2902277#2902277).

It looks a bit strange that you are passing a .c file to g95. You should compile the C file using GCC, then link the resulting .o file to your compiled fortran code.